# AJAX/JS: Echoing value of a div without page refresh or button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently working with an wmd editor that i will later implement to my website. I have been able to get the value of the `#wmd-preview` div by changing the settings to `markdown` and adding a hidden input field. The issue is with the JS/AJAX function. When I type something in the text area I get the result echoed but when i go back and apply bold to the word it doesnt echo the change until i actually type something again.

How can i get the div value echoed when a font style change has been applied to a word without having to type again? Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var timer = null; 
        var dataString;   
        function submitForm(){
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
             url: "test1.php",
             data: dataString,
             success: function(result){
        $('#wmd_result').html( $('#resultval', result).html()); 
                    }
    });
     return false;
}

 $('#wmd-input').on('keyup click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);
    var wmdVal = $("#wmd-preview").html();
    dataString = 'wmdVal='+ wmdVal;
});
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
$('#wmd-button-bar').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);
    var wmdVal = $("#wmd-preview").html();
    dataString = 'wmdVal='+ wmdVal;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work if you e.g. click on the word, it just that you only have `keyup` and `click` as event handlers. Try adding `change` as well and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the change event instead?

```
 $('#wmd-input').change(function() {
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);
var wmdVal = $("#wmd-preview").html();
dataString = 'wmdVal='+ wmdVal;
```

});

Comment: Change events are user triggered. The textarea's value is being modified by a script so the change event won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

You're only listening for events on the `#wmd-input` textarea. *Clicking the bold button* might change the contents of that text area, but it's not an editing event and no events are triggered in the browser. *You* aren't changing the text area, some function tied to the button *you pressed* is changing it.

Add a click listener to `.wmd-button` and you'll be able to capture that event.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joemaller/uR6FN/) demonstrating how it might work.

**Edit:** Added code example.

All you need to do is add the `.wmd-button` class to your jQuery listener, like this:

```
 $('#wmd-input, .wmd-button').on('keyup click', function() {...
```

You would usually want to pay attention to listener order to make sure your code is executed  after the wmd styling code, but because you've got a timeout in your function it likely won't matter.

Comment: +1 Thank you, this is heading in the right direction. Can you apply that to my example JS function and I will accept your answer my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest another way you might want to consider.

Handling events can turn to a monster. for example - someone offered the following code line
`$('#wmd-input, .wmd-button').on('keyup click', function() {...`

This will cause an event every time you click on the input field!! ( you click on input field every time you want to focus it for editing ).

Don't forget that there can be many events every second - which might get the server exploded with requests.

A better way might be to set an interval function, this method will read the value from the input field and compare it to last value it has. 
If something changes - go ahead and make an Ajax request, otherwise, do nothing.

This way you control the rate in which the Ajax request is made, and you don't have to worry about any event ever! If suddenly you have a new set of buttons, or input fields, or popus to insert images or whatever... life is simply easier this way.

On the down side - as the interval is bigger - you get a delay between typing and previewing.

pseudo-code for this interval method looks like this

```
$(function(){
    var lastValue = null;
    setInterval( function(){
         var newValue =   $("#wmd-preview").html();

         if ( lastValue == null || newValue.localeCompare( lastValue ) == 0 ){
               lastValue = newValue;
               // preview code here
         }

         // else do nothing
    }, 1000 );
});
```